# How to run widget over the container screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show some widget onTap() event over screen like below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6chFX.png) .

Here is my code
In this the build method is return `Container()`.
Container has one child named `SingleChildScrollView` and also it has some children.

So I don't want to change on this all children when new widget will create.

In simple, saw widget `onTap()` over the running screen without disturb another widget.

```
class _SettingScreenState extends State<SettingScreen> {

  List<Widget> _iconList=[];
  List<Widget> _titleList=[];
  List<Widget> _settingLIst=[];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      _iconList.add(_addInIcon(i));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      _titleList.add(_addInTitle(i));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<24;i++){
      _settingLIst.add(_addInSetting(i));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _titleList[0],
            _addInSetting(0),
            _addInSetting(1),
            _titleList[1],
            _settingLIst[2],
            _settingLIst[3],
            _titleList[2],
            _settingLIst[4],
            _settingLIst[5],
            _settingLIst[6],
            _settingLIst[7],
            _settingLIst[8],
            _settingLIst[9],
            GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              //open widget over the this screen
            },
            child: Button(
              image: _coverImage(),
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 50,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
          ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ans , is setState() is necessary while create new widget over the previous `Container()` widget ?
Because we cant change anything on previous `Container()`

In Android-java development, what i did

```
onClick()
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(position).into(imageView);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( Math.round((float) 35 * density),  Math.round((float) 35 * density));
        imageView.setX(reactionButton.getX());
        imageView.setY(reactionButton.getY());
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        messageRelativeLayout.addView(imageView);
        imageView.bringToFront();
        animateReaction(imageView);
    }
```

It means every time new ImageView will added on tree, no matter if previous ImageView is appear or not.
Simple click button and create new ImageView and show front of screen.

this feature i want to apply in flutter

Comment: Should it be visible at fixed position or will move according to scroll?

Comment: yes it will on fixed position and please dont suggest alertDialog, created widget will be an animated widget

Comment: search about the widget stack

Comment: @M.Nasri after searching of few hours , than i was came here to ask, i was not able to find correct model like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Child of OverlayWidget**

```dart
class OverlayChild extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function clearCallBack;
  final double maxWidth;
  final double maxHeight;
  final int itemIndex;

  const OverlayChild({
    Key? key,
    required this.clearCallBack,
    required this.maxWidth,
    required this.maxHeight,
    required this.itemIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OverlayChildState createState() => _OverlayChildState();
}

class _OverlayChildState extends State<OverlayChild> {
  late Timer timer;
  final Random random = Random();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("int  ${widget.itemIndex}");
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        widget.clearCallBack(widget.itemIndex);
        timer.cancel();
        print("after delay");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: random.nextDouble() * widget.maxHeight,
      left: random.nextDouble() * widget.maxWidth,
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        width: 20,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color:
              widget.itemIndex.isEven ? Colors.deepPurple : Colors.cyanAccent,
        ),
        child: Center(child: Text("${widget.itemIndex}")),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Main Widget**

```dart
class HomeOverLay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<HomeOverLay> {
  List<OverlayChild> overlayItems = [];

  int itemId = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            setState(() {
              overlayItems.add(
                OverlayChild(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  clearCallBack: (id) {
                    setState(() {
                      overlayItems
                          .removeWhere((element) => element.itemIndex == id);
                    });
                  },
                  itemIndex: itemId,
                  //same as container height
                  maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
                  maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                ),
              );

              itemId++;
            });
          },
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter, // you may want some changes here
              child: SizedBox(
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(
                        22,
                        (index) => Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          color: index.isEven
                              ? Colors.deepPurple
                              : Colors.orangeAccent,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: constraints.maxHeight * .2,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: overlayItems.length > 0 ? constraints.maxWidth : 0,
                height:
                    overlayItems.length > 0 ? constraints.maxHeight * .1 : 0,
                color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    ...overlayItems.toList(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in these code you declared.
show and !show.means widget will create only once, But in my case new widget will create every time onTap();

Comment: don't you want to control visibility?  Then you can remove this bool. or something else you are looking for?

Comment: Does my updated answer satisfy your conditions about overlay?

Comment: you can see this image https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgiphy.com%2Fgifs%2Fcolorfest-like-color-fest-j6SOkiGmvH0qbdLwMz&psig=AOvVaw3VXj89Zx7EHqdekOIDeEro&ust=1629675135349000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCODE9J6jw_ICFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD    , in this GIF all images are widget create by onTap() and background screen is Container()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236273/discussion-between-vora-ravi-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Comment: The Perfect Answer